# QML model inside model is undefined

Tags: qml, qt5, qt-quick, qabstractlistmodel

I have a `QAbstractListModel` called `SerialPortList` which represents a list of `SerialPort`s. Each `SerialPort` has a `QList<int> supportedBaudRates` property. The `SerialPortList` model's `display` role is simply `QVariant::fromValue(mSerialPorts[i])`, i.e. a `SerialPort` instance.

I display my list model in a `Repeater` like this (highly simplified):

```
SerialPortList {
    id: ports
}

Column {
    Repeater {
        id: portList
        // ...
        model: ports
        Text { text: model.display.portName }
        ComboBox {
            model: model.display.supportedBaudRates
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

That is, a list of the serial ports name, and then a combo box with its supported baud rates.

The weird thing is, although the text is displayed fine, apparently for the combo box `model.display` is undefined. If I replace the combo box with this:

```
            Text {
                text: model.display.supportedBaudRates.join(" ")
            }
```

then it produces the result you'd expect!

What is going on here? I can only assume that `model` is redefined inside the `ComboBox` so it thinks it is referring to itself, but I've tried all kinds of id references like `portList.model.display.supportedBaudRates` that I can think of and none of them work.

**Edit**

Kakadu pointed out that you can't use a `QList<int>` as a model. Kind of annoying, but I've changed it to `QStringList` which you apparently can use. Sadly the error remains the same.

**Edit 2**

I changed the `model:` in the `ComboBox` to `model: { console.log("model: " + model); }` and it prints `1`, which makes me sure that `model` refers to itself.

Comment: AFAIR you can't use QList as a model for View. See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753419 . Btw, you have very much points there so it seems that I have read your question wrong and problem is somewhere else. I'm sorry if it have happened.

Comment: Ah it seems you are correct - you can only use `QList<QObject*>` `QList<QString>`, a `QAbstractItemModel`-derived class, or a single integer as a model. Well that sucks. For now I will work around it by duplicating the property as a `QStringList`. Hacky but I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Actually it still doesn't work - `model.display` is `undefined` still, but only when it is the target of another model.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I finally got it to work! It's simply a namespace problem - `model` is something of a magic variable so you can't use id qualifiers on it.

Fortunately `model.` is implicitly prepended to any variable accesses in the delegate, so I changed my code to this and it worked:

```
    ComboBox {
        model: display.supportedBaudRatesAsStrings
        // ...
    }
```

(The `...AsStrings` property is a `QStringList` duplicate of the original `QList<int>` property.)